# How to force ctest only run unit tests in some subdirectories?

Tags: cmake, cxxtest

My cmake project has the following tree structure:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── basis
├── build
├── deps
├── study
```

where `/deps` contains all 3rd-party dependencies, `/basis` and `/study` directories contain routines I wrote.

In my main CMakeLists.txt file, I have the following code to enable CxxTest

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(study_cmake)

set( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug"  )
add_subdirectory(deps/eigen)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/cxxtest/)
find_package(CxxTest REQUIRED)
if(CXXTEST_FOUND)
    include_directories(${CXXTEST_INCLUDE_DIR})
    message( 'CXXTEST_INCLUDE_DIR:' ${CXXTEST_INCLUDE_DIR} )
    enable_testing()
endif()

add_subdirectory(study) 
add_subdirectory(basis)
```

In `/basis/CMakeLists.txt`, I have

```
project(basis)
add_library(
    basis
    include/bernstein.h
    src/bernstein.cpp
)

CXXTEST_ADD_TEST(test_bernstein test_bernstein.cc ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test/test_bernstein.h
```

In `/study/CMakeLists.txt`, I have similar things as in `/basis/CMakeLists.txt`. After running `cmake ..` and `make` in the `build` directory, I can run `ctest` in `build/basis/`, `build/study/`to run unit tests defined in these two subdirectories separately. But I would like to have a way to run all unit tests defined in these two subdirectories, so I tried run `ctest` in `/build/`. Unfortunately, this command seems also to run all unit tests defined in 3d-party dependencies in `/deps/`. How can we force `ctest` only run all unit tests defined in `build/basis/` and `build/study/` by myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I'd try is `ctest`'s regex selectors. From `ctest --help`

```
  -L <regex>, --label-regex <regex>
                               = Run tests with labels matching regular
                                 expression.
  -R <regex>, --tests-regex <regex>
                               = Run tests matching regular expression.
  -E <regex>, --exclude-regex <regex>
                               = Exclude tests matching regular expression.
  -LE <regex>, --label-exclude <regex>
                               = Exclude tests with labels matching regular
                                 expression.
```

If you wanted to group a bunch of tests together you could set labels on them.

```
CXXTEST_ADD_TEST(test_bernstein test_bernstein.cc ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test/test_bernstein.h
CXXTEST_ADD_TEST(test_scarry test_scarry.cc ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test/test_scarry.h
CXXTEST_ADD_TEST(test_mayer test_mayer.cc ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test/test_mayer.h
CXXTEST_ADD_TEST(test_king test_king.cc ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test/test_king.h

set_tests_properties(test_bernstein test_scarry test_mayer PROPERTIES LABELS "fun")
set_tests_properties(test_king PROPERTIES LABELS "scary")
```

Note that `set_tests_properties()` only defines properties on tests created with `add_test()` (which `CXXTEST_ADD_TEST` does behind the scenes.) Then you could run `ctest -L fun` to run only the "fun" tests.

```
$ ctest -L fun
Test project /home/me/myproject
     Start 1: test_bernstein
 1/3 Test #1: test_bernstein ..............   Passed    2.19 sec
     Start 2: test_scarry
 2/3 Test #2: test_scarry .................   Passed    2.19 sec
     Start 3: test_mayer
 3/3 Test #3: test_mayer ..................   Passed    2.19 sec
100% tests passed out of 23

Total Test time (real) =  6.57 sec

$
```

Comment: This works for me. However, I wonder if there are other better ways to specify ctest only run unit tests in some specific directories.

Comment: from your build directory, `cd basis; ctest`. (of course that may depend on how you've defined your tests)

Comment: I would like to run all tests in ```/basis``` and ```/study``` together rather than getting into ```/basis``` and ```/study``` separately and run tests there. You answer posted above works because I can label all tests in ```/basis``` and ```/study``` with the same label, say ```fun```. Then I can use ```ctest -L fun``` in my ```/build``` directory to run all tests in ```/basis``` and ```/study```.